# Using singleton in a singleton

Tags: c#, singleton

With the risk of being declared stupid...

I came across a problem today which made me a bit confused.

I'm having two singleton objects, a loggger and an ethernethandler. The ethernethandler is using the logger instance for logging exceptions related to ethernet connection in a .net mf application.

```
public sealed class Logger
{
    class InternalLogger
    {
        static InternalLogger()
        {}

        internal static readonly Logger instance = new Logger();
    }

    public static Logger GetInstance 
    {
        get { return InternalLogger.instance; }    
    }

    private Logger()
    {}
}


public sealed class EthernetHandler
{
    public Logger Logger = Logger.GetInstance;

    class InternalEthernetHandler
    {
        static InternalEthernetHandler()
        {}

        internal static readonly EthernetHandler instance = new EthernetHandler();
    }

    public static EthernetHandler GetInstance 
    {
        get { return InternalEthernetHandler.instance; }    
    }

    private EthernetHandler()
    {}
}
```

For some reason the Logger property of the EthernetHandler is null. Could someone explain this to me and suggest a solution.

Comment: There are some compile time errors in your logger because your constructors don't match your class names.  When fixing those errors, everything works just fine, as I'd expect.  Is this in fact your real code?  Also, you're doing way more work than you need to for your singletons.  There's no need for them to each have an internal class to hold the static variable.  You can pull the variable out and remove the internal classes without any problems.

Comment: Sorry I have fixed that now and I am aware of that there are other ways of implementing the singleton pattern. However, all of them generates the same result, that is, The Logger property is null.

Comment: None of them generate the result that the logger is `null`.

Comment: Have you tried it in .net mf?

Comment: What do you mean by mf?

Comment: .Net micro framework.

Comment: No, although I'd be pretty surprised to find out that they had a bug in this behavior; it's actually reasonably straightforward.

Comment: .net mf is using a subset of the .net clr. I have encountered lots of other bug so I would not be so surprised. Thanks for the help.